# Convert a text into time format using bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am new to shell scripting.. I have a tab-separated file, e.g.,

```
0018803 01  1710    2050    002571      
0018951 01  1934    2525    003277  
0019362 02  2404    2415    002829  
0019392 01  2621    2820    001924  
0019542 01  2208    2413    003434  
0019583 01  1815    2134    002971
```

Here, the 3rd and 4th column is representing Start Time and End Time.

I want to convert these two columns in proper timeFrame so that I can get 6th column as the exact time difference between column `4` and column `3` in hours and minutes.

Column `6` result will be `3:40`, `5:51`, `00:11`, `1:59`, `2:05`.

Comment: Note: If a person live on internet from 2300 hrs to next day 200 hours, the start time will be 2300 and end time will be 2400+200 = 2600

Comment: `representing Start Time and End Time` in what format?

Comment: Start Time and End Time are in  "hh:mm"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way with `awk`:

```
$ cat test.awk
# create a function to split hour and minute
function f(h, x) {
    h[0] = substr(x,1,2)+0
    h[1] = substr(x,3,2)+0
}

{
    f(start, $3);
    f(end, $4);
    span  = end[1] - start[1] > 0 \
          ? sprintf("%d:%02d", end[0]-start[0], end[1]-start[1]) \
          : sprintf("%d:%02d", end[0]-start[0]-1, 60+end[1]-start[1]);
    print $0 OFS span
}
```

then run the awk file as the following:

```
$ awk -f test.awk input_file
```

**Edit:** per @glenn jackman's suggestion, the code can be simplified (refer to @Kamil Cuk's method):

```
function g(x) {
    return substr(x,1,2)*60 + substr(x,3,2)
}

{
    span = g($4) - g($3)
    printf("%s%s%d:%02d\n", $0, OFS, int(span/60), span%60)
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest you make `f` return an integral number of minutes, then create function `g` which converts a number of minutes to HH:MM format. That will allow to you remove that very ugly ternary.

Comment: Also, the tidier `print $0, span` uses the OFS to separate the items.

Answer (score 2):

A simple bash solution using arithmetic expansion:

```
while IFS='' read -r l; do
        IFS=' ' read -r _ _ st et _ <<<"$l"
        d=$(( (10#${et:0:2} * 60 + 10#${et:2:2}) - (10#${st:0:2} * 60 + 10#${st:2:2}) ))
        printf "%s %02d:%02d\n" "$l" "$((d/60))" "$((d%60))"
done < intput_file_path
```

will output:

```
0018803 01  1710    2050    002571   03:40
0018951 01  1934    2525    003277   05:51
0019362 02  2404    2415    002829   00:11
0019392 01  2621    2820    001924   01:59
0019542 01  2208    2413    003434   02:05
0019583 01  1815    2134    002971   03:19
```

Comment: what's that `10#` for?

Comment: Just about exactly what I came up with. You might want to refactor some of the work into functions. e.g. `ts2mins() { local h=${1:0:2} m=${1:2:2}; echo $(( 10#$h * 60 + 10#$m )); }` then `d=$(( $(ts2mins $et) - $(ts2mins $st) ))`

Comment: @Sam Shel interprets numbers like `02` as octals (usually). So to make it interpret in base 10, you need to add `10#` in front of it. For example for `2404` for `${et:2:2}` you will extract `04`. We want that to be interpreted as `4` in base 10, so we add `10#04`.

Comment: The octal problem is especially important when the hour or minute is `08` or `09` -- without specifically using base 10, bash will throw "invalid octal" errors. Try with `echo $((08))` vs `echo $((10#08))`

Answer (score 1):

Here is one in GNU awk using [time functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html), `mktime` to convert to epoch time and `strftime` to convert the time to desired format `HH:MM`:

```
$ awk -v OFS="\t" '{
    dt3="1970 01 01 " substr($3,1,2) " " substr($3,3,2) " 00"
    dt4="1970 01 01 " substr($4,1,2) " " substr($4,3,2) " 00"
    print $0,strftime("%H:%M",mktime(dt4)-mktime(dt3),1)      # thanks @glennjackman,1 :)
}' file
```

Output ($6 only):

```
03:40
05:51
00:11
01:59
02:05
03:19
```

Comment: It's a smart idea to use the builtin time functions. To account for time zones, tell `strftime` to use UTC instead of hardcoding your offset: `strftime("%H:%M",mktime(dt4)-mktime(dt3), 1)` -- https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html